# Emacs: M-d has to be pressed twice to delete

Tags: macos, ubuntu, emacs, vmware, key-bindings

It's emacs running in Ubuntu in VMware on a Mac. :-(

I found this problem with emacs, when I tried to use M-d to delete words (or M-del), I had to press it twice to get it work. The first time it has no effect while the second time it works.

If I use Esc-delete to delete words, it always works the first time I pressed it.

I already set mappings from Mac's Option->Alt.

Can anyone explain why this twice things is happening and how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: VMWare key-mapping is the root cause. Disabled it by unchecking `Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Key Mappings -> Enable Key Mappings`.